# How to export this excel spreadsheet in this format?

Tags: vbscript, excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheet with 875 rows and 6 columns .

How can I export all the data (possibly with vb script?) into a txt file like this..

**row = 1**

array(
'name'=>'*column1data*',
'address'=>'*column2data*',
'telephone'=>'*column3data*',
'email'=>'*column3data*',
'website'=>'*column4data*',
'latitude'=>'*column5data*',
'longitude'=>'*column6data*'
),

**increment row number and repeat the above until the end of rows**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest thing for you to do is to create a column in the spreadsheet with the following formula

```
="array(
'name'=>'"&A1&"',
'address'=>'"&B1&"',
'telephone'=>'"&C1&"',
'email'=>'"&D1&"',
'website'=>'"&E1&"',
'latitude'=>'"&F1&"',
'longitude'=>'"&G1&"'
),"
```

As you can see, the idea is basically to build up the string, say in column H, then just copy and paste your new information wherever you like. Side note, I forget at the moment if the single quotes will work in the formula above, you may have to escape them.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :) Now how do I get it to carriage return in the above format.. as it now displays on one line?

Comment: @Dooooob To add a carriage return in the same cell, press the ALT key and the Enter key at the same time.